# Angular render buttons in footer outside router-outlet

Tags: angular, router

My index.html has a header with a navbar, a div container with the router-outlet in it and a footer. The component templates render within in the router-outlet but I also want to render buttons (back, save, other buttons) into the footer from the component. How do I do this?

Comment: Show some code. better if you create a plunker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the presentation done by Alex Rickabaugh (angular core), about creating a left nav component with content dictated by the routed components.

[Advanced Angular Concepts by Alex Rickabaugh](https://youtu.be/rKbY1t39dHU)

After you implement this solution, you can use it like this:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <left-nav></left-nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {}
```

**some-routed.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `
<h2>I am Route A</h2>

<div *leftNav>
  <h3>Route A Nav</h3>
</div>
`
})
export class SomeComponent {}
```

You can inspect the entire implementation in this [Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/adv-ng-left-nav)

Comment: finally tried this and it works. however I can only get this to work within one module. I need the directive (*leftNav in your example) to display in the main module, and supply the content from a component in a child module.

Comment: to get around the issue that it did not work in a different module, included references to the directive and service in a common module. That works!

Comment: @Mcanic Hi, I am also trying to share that directive from a common module, then use it in the app-module and a library module, but always get 'my-directive' is not a known element. how did you make it work?